# What would be the best way to connect to Facebook via C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, facebook, api, qt

I'm looking to create a desktop app in C/C++, most likely with Qt, that has the ability to connect (read/post) to Facebook. Which got me thinking, how exactly would you go about doing such a task? I know many desktop apps written in C++, such as Spotify, have the ability to do it. Are there any good libraries available? What's the common way to do it? Will I have to parse Javascript or PHP in C++? I know there's a C# API, which I've used, and it worked fine. Anything similar for C++? Thanks!

Comment: I imagine I'd start @ [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/)/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get a C++ json interpreter you can use the Graph API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/. You make queries over HTTPs and get a response in JSON that you can use however you want.

Comment: Decided to use the Python API with the Python C API as an interpreter. Thanks anyway though.